# How to enable multi touch on click buttons?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton, buttonclick

I couldn't find an answer online. When I hold my phone with my hand, the palm of my hand touches the screen's bottom corner and it prevents/blocks any future clicks on buttons with my fingers on the screen. I need to enable multi-touch for buttons but not sure how to do it. I use buttons and (onClick component) but they don't work when I hold my phone with my palm. I need to tell the app- ignore previous clicks and count only the latest click

Answer (score 1):

It's possible only via [IPointerClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) and other `IPointer...Handler`.
Please refer to `UnityEngine.EventSystems` namespace.